# How to add background color and a number in sparkline cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a whole list of begin and end-dates. For each pair, I would like to see the progress based on the current date in a sparkline:

```
   A            B
1  BeginDate    EndDate
2  21.01.2023   21.10.2023
```

For instance, if today is `30.04.2023`  (I use DD.MM.YYYY format), then the sparkline looks like:

[image]

The formula I use for this is:

```
=SPARKLINE(MAX(0,TODAY()-A2),{"charttype","bar";"max",MAX(1,B2-A2)})
```

However, I am unable to set a background color, like below:

[image]

- Q1: How can I update my formula so that the (100%) beckground color is blue and the progress bar itself is orange (like now; it seems to be a default color bc I haven't defined any color?)
- Q2: Is it possible to - in addition to the progress bar - have the percentage been written as number in the same cell (see mockup below)?

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: Rather than defining the maximum for the bars in the *options* argument, add a second data point to the *data* argument corresponding to the difference between the end date and today using an array literal:

```
=SPARKLINE({MAX(0,TODAY()-A2),B2-TODAY()},{"charttype","bar"})
```

Q2: I'm 99.9% certain this is not possible, I'm afraid.